# Drag & Drop Option is not working for all folders in imap php

Tags: php, drag-and-drop, imap

I am doing the webmail project in php using imap function.
We can Drag & Drop mail item one folder to another folder but that is working for INBOX folder messages only. I don't know why. Is their any mail settings need ? or my coding mistake ?

This is my coding to move to the another folder,

```
$imapresult = @imap_mail_move($mbox,$move_uid,$mailbox,CP_UID);
        if($imapresult==false){die("error".imap_last_error());}
        //delete selected email from current folder
        @imap_expunge($mbox);
        imap_close($mbox,CL_EXPUNGE);
```

Comment: move message from "INBOX" folder only. Is their any mail settings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is working for one folder, then it should work for others also.

Please check if you have any specific dropable options for INBOX. Also check the from folder and to folder in the move method.

Comment: thanks vinoth. You are right. I connect imap_open with INBOX folder only. I have changed the folder name dynamically it is working fine.